# Most efficient way to remove punctuation marks from string in c++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, strlen

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to remove punctuation marks from a string in c++, this is what I currently have.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void PARSE(string a);

int main()
{
    string f;
    PARSE(f);
    cout << f;
}

void PARSE(string a)
{
    a = "aBc!d:f'a";

    a.erase(remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), ispunct), a.end());

    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Is there a easier/more efficient way to do this?

I was thinking using str.len, get the length of the string, run it through a for loop and check ispunct then remove if it is.

Comment: "_I was thinking using str.len, get the length of the string, run it through a for loop and check ispunct then remove if it is._"  That's almost exactly what your `erase` and `remove_if` calls are doing.  What makes you think doing it yourself would be easier, more efficient, or less error prone than using the highly optimized, heavily tested standard library functions.

Comment: What makes you think using the [*erase-remove idiom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase–remove_idiom) like that wouldn't be the most "efficient" way? Have you measured that this is a bottleneck in your program? And like the previous commenter say, trying to implement this yourself will be way messier and much more prone to errors and bugs.

Comment: Looking for the part of the question where it says something along the lines of *"I know there is a more efficient way to do this, what is it?"* as the 2 comments above imply. Only finding the question *"Is there a easier/more efficient way to do this?"*

Comment: As a matter of fact, your way is **less** efficient than `erase / remove_if`.  Your method calls `erase` each time an element is found, meaning the string has to shrink, i.e. cover up the hole made by the call to `erase`.  The `remove_if` does **not** erase items, merely places the items at the end of the sequence.  **The sequence does not change size**.  Then the final call to `erase` erases a contiguous set of characters, thus essentially only one "big hole" at the end needs to be replaced, not several as in your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No string copies. No heap allocation. No heap deallocation.

```
void strip_punct(string& inp)
{
    auto to = begin(inp);   
    for (auto from : inp)
        if (!ispunct(from)) 
            *to++ = from;
    inp.resize(distance(begin(inp), to));
}
```

Comparing to:

```
void strip_punct_re(string& inp)
{
    inp.erase(remove_if(begin(inp), end(inp), ispunct), end(inp));
}
```

I created a variety of workloads. As a baseline input, I created a string containing all char values between 32 and 127.  I appended this string `num`-times to create my test string.  I called both `strip_punct` and `strip_punct_re` with a copy of the test string `iters`-times. I performed these workloads 10 times timing each test.  I averaged the timings after dropping the lowest and highest results.  I tested using release builds (optimized) from VS2015 on Windows 10 on a Microsoft Surface Book 4 (Skylake).  I `SetPriorityClass()` for the process to `HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS` and timed the results using `QueryPerformanceFrequency/QueryPerformanceCounter`. All timings were performed without a debugger attached.

```
 num        iters      seconds      seconds (re)    improvement
10000        1000        2.812        2.947             4.78%  
 1000       10000        2.786        2.977             6.85%
  100      100000        2.809        2.952             5.09%
```

By varying num and iters while keeping the number of processed bytes the same, I was able to see that the cost is primarily influenced by the number of bytes processed rather than per-call overhead.  Reading the disassembly confirmed this.

So this version, is ~5% faster and generates 30% of the code.

Comment: What does this gain you over remove/erase?

Comment: Also, I do not see if you were testing a release, optimized version or debug, unoptimized version.  If it's the latter, then your results are meaningless.

Comment: Updated to include release build annotation